# How to push text into newly created file by shell script from PHP?

Tags: php

i used PHP site to run a shell script and it created my desired name file "result.txt" inside /opt/xampp/htdocs. However, the result.txt is totally empty, when it is supposed to have output values from the shell script. Tried on terminal, result.txt is created on Desktop and outputs are there. Tried on PHP, result.txt is created but totally no outputs are inside.

It's a long script so here's the first few lines:

```
# creates result.txt
touch result.txt

##makes the .txt read only
chmod 444 result.txt 


clear


###################################################
# This option audits the password and             #
# shadow files on the system                      #
###################################################

##option 2.1.1
echo -e "=========================================================================================" >> result.txt
echo "                                  SHADOWED PASSWORD CHECK                                   " >> result.txt
echo "=========================================================================================" >> result.txt
```

Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code you are using to run the shell script

Comment: <?php

  exec('/Desktop/test.sh');
 
?>
Am a total newbie in PHP

Comment: What does the shell script contain?

Comment: It contains basic IT System Auditing codes. It creates a file named "result.txt" and push every test output to it in the single script.

Comment: It would be useful to see them - the exec() call is fine, the only difference to running it from a command line is usually that PHP runs under a different user.

Comment: Oh ya, I am "nobody" in PHP. How do I change to "root"? Anyway, a sample is uploaded in the post. thanks for helping

Comment: See [How to change privilege in PHP from nobody to root?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7633860)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change privilege in PHP from nobody to root?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633860/how-to-change-privilege-in-php-from-nobody-to-root)

Comment: That's my own thread, and i am still looking for a solution

Comment: If you already know why this happens, why do you ask it again? And the other question *has* a solution in the duplicate link

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is completely unnecessary to redirect the output of every echo call - use this at the start of your shell script to have STDOUT redirected to your output file.

```
exec &> results.txt
```

Secondly - your chmod to 444 will not leave the file writeable by the Apache/PHP user - I'd perform this at the very end of your script, if even needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing working directory first, using chdir($folder).

```
<?php
chdir("/testfolder/");
exec("./script.sh");
?>
```

But, why not write the script as php? Things like touch, chmod and every other command available in the unix shell is easily available in php.